# Flush incognito windows in chrome automatically on hibernate

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, script

Is there a way to setup chrome so that any incognito windows I've opened can be flushes (closed) automatically on hibernate?

If not natively is there a scripted way in chrome or windows 10 to achieve this?

Comment: You can use taskkill to kill chrome, and use task scheduler to execute taskkill when the pc goes to hibernation. Do note, this stops chrome completely, not just the incognito windows.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything to filter out the incognito windows instead or all chrome windows?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You can filter based on window title, but I'm sure that makes even more complicated, given that you likely won't have the same windows titles in your incognito tabs.